# Why is my Perl in-place script exiting with a zero exit code even though it's failing?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a one-liner Perl search and replace that looks roughly like this:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt
```

Because the file doesn't exist (which isn't intentional, but this is part of an automated build script, so I want to protect against that), Perl exits with this error:

```
Can't open non-existent-file.txt: No such file or directory.
```

However, the exit code is still zero:

```
echo $?
0
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be modifying my script, or the way I'm invoking Perl? I was naively assuming that because Perl couldn't find the file, it would exit with a non-zero code.

Comment: Perl does not automatically exit when it is unable to open a file. That one liner is a real script for Perl, so when it comes to the open, it just tries to open the file. It is not able to and thus writes to STDERR but it can not know whether there is something else to do in the rest of the script and so it just goes on. In this case, there is nothing else to do as it would just loop over the lines of the file. And thus it finishes normally at the end of the script, returning zero. If you want your script to `die` or `exit` with some specific error code, you have to add that to the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force error by dying,

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die"no file" } s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt
```

Comment: Note: Doesn't handle permission errors or multiple files. Also, it dies when provided a pipe or socket.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's not a fatal error. If you use `perl -pe'...' file1 file2`, it would continue to process `file2` even if `file1` doesn't exist.

The following causes the issuance of any warning to result in a non-zero exit code.

```
$ perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN {
      $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
         ++$error;
         print STDERR $_[0];
      };
    }

    END { $? ||= 1 if $error; }

    s/foo/bar/g;
' file1 file2
```

This means that `file2` will still be processed even if `file1` doesn't exist, but the exit code will be non-zero.