# need perl to die when implicit open fails

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to migrate a `sed` script to a perl one-liner, because perl supports non-greedy regexp. I've taken advices from [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed) and [Why is my Perl in-place script exiting with a zero exit code even though it's failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192300/why-is-my-perl-in-place-script-exiting-with-a-zero-exit-code-even-though-its-fa)

I need my oneliner to exit with non-zero status if it failed to open the file.

Unfortunately, checking `-f $ARGV[0]` is unreliable, because the file may exist and still be inaccessible.

One idea is to add some perl code to execute between all files in command line, but I can't find one. `END` is executed once and if the last file succeeded, then it won't know that previous files failed.

```
touch aaa.txt
chmod 000 aaa.txt
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN { -f $ARGV[0] or die "fatal: " . $!; }' aaa.txt; echo $?
```

_

```
Can't open aaa.txt: Permission denied.
0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Can't open ...` text is a warning. You can trap that using the `$SIG{__WARN__}` signal handler.

As the only warnings you should be getting are from the implicit `<>` operator in the loop supplied by the `-p` switch you can rewrite your code like this

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN { $exit = 0; $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { $exit = 1; warn @_} } END { $? = $exit}' aaa.txt; echo $?
```

This sets `$exit` to 0 at the start of the script and sets it to 1 if there is a warning. The `END` block assigns the value of `$exit` to `$?` which will be the exit code of the script once it ends.