# perl - get non-zero exit code if at least one of the listed files does not exist

Tags: perl

As for the cat command, which returns an exit code other than 0 if at least one file in the list does not exist, but continuing its execution, I would also like the same behavior for the "perl" command, which while continuing its execution, unfortunately it does not return a non-0 exit code when encountering one or more missing files.

This solution provided by another topic [Why is my Perl in-place script exiting with a zero exit code even though it's failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192300):

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die"no file" } s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt
```

Correctly returns a non-0 exit code when a file is not found but does not continue executing for other files. Indeed this:

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die"no file" } s/foo/bar/' non-existent-file.txt existent-file.txt
```

doesn't give the output of the second file but only the error for the first non-existent file.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: There's no way to configure reading from `ARGV`. If you don't like how it works, you'd have to reimplement it with your modifications. (In other words, get rid of `-p`, and use `for ( @ARGV ) { ... }`.)

Comment: I don't understand the problem with an answer (ikegami's) in the link you provide?  It continues processing but it exits with non-zero if there were errors -- isn't that what you are asking for?  In the example you took from that link, shown here, there is an explicit `die` ... of course it exits at that point?

Comment: LIke `perl -MList::MoreUtils=any -wpE'BEGIN { $fail = 7 if any { not -f } @ARGV } END { exit ($fail //= 0) }' nofile yesfile`.  Then `echo $?`

Comment: In short, you can `exit` with a desired code in an `END` block, and that will be in shell's `$?`. So keep a flag throughout that gets set for error conditions and use it for `exit`.   (Or better yet an array like in mob's answer so you can actually print those errors as well)

Answer (score 2):

Put your `die` statement in an `END` block instead of a `BEGIN` block.

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ @nf=grep ! -f $_, @ARGV}
    END{die "not found: @nf" if @nf} 
    s/foo/bar/' file1 file2 ...
```